# How to desible multiline in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I mistakenely had to click on something and in one file in android studio when I want to tick the code I have multiline ticking( screenShot)

How to disable that? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFEoy.png)

Comment: It happens everytime I want to tick the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in the editor and uncheck "Column Selection Mode" from the context menu just opened.